# How to apply correct discount on a product ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I'm trying to modify a shipment inventory code to apply the discount on a product in percentage and not as a value. Now if my `totalAmount` is 1200$ and the discount value is 20, the `totalAmount` will be 1180$, instead I wish it was 960$ (totalOrder - 20%).

I modified the code and now I have almost the right value, my totalOrder is 960-discountAmount = 940$

`SalesOrder` class:

```
[Display(Name = "Sales Order Lines")]
public List<SalesOrderLine> salesOrderLine { get; set; } = new List<SalesOrderLine>();
```

`SalesOrderLine` class:

```
public SalesOrderLine()
{
   this.createdAt = DateTime.UtcNow;
   this.discountAmount = 0m;
   this.totalAmount = 0m;
}
```

`SalesOrderController` class:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ShowSalesOrder(string id)
{
    SalesOrder obj = await _context.SalesOrder
        .Include(x => x.customer)
        .Include(x => x.salesOrderLine).ThenInclude(x => x.product)
        .Include(x => x.branch)
        .SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.salesOrderId.Equals(id));

    obj.totalOrderAmount = obj.salesOrderLine.Sum(x => x.totalAmount);
    _context.Update(obj);

    return View(obj);
}

public async Task<IActionResult> PrintSalesOrder(string id)
{
    SalesOrder obj = await _context.SalesOrder
        .Include(x => x.customer)
        .Include(x => x.salesOrderLine).ThenInclude(x => x.product)
        .Include(x => x.branch)
        .SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.salesOrderId.Equals(id));
    return View(obj);
}

public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var applicationDbContext = _context.SalesOrder.OrderByDescending(x => x.createdAt).Include(s => s.customer);
    return View(await applicationDbContext.ToListAsync());
}

public async Task<IActionResult> Details(string id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var salesOrder = await _context.SalesOrder
            .Include(x => x.salesOrderLine)
            .Include(s => s.customer)
            .Include(x => x.branch)
                .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.salesOrderId == id);

    if (salesOrder == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    ViewData["branchId"] = new SelectList(_context.Branch, "branchId", "branchName", salesOrder.branchId);
    ViewData["customerId"] = new SelectList(_context.Customer, "customerId", "customerName", salesOrder.customerId);

    salesOrder.totalOrderAmount = salesOrder.salesOrderLine.Sum(x => x.totalAmount);
    _context.Update(salesOrder);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return View(salesOrder);
}
```

`ShowSalesOrder.cshtml` view:

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model.salesOrderLine)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.qty</td>
            <td>@item.product.productCode</td>
            <td>@item.price.ToString()</td>
            <td>@item.product.productName</td>
            <td>$ @item.totalAmount</td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

What should I do to fix the problem?

Comment: `discountAmount` is a _dollar_ discount amount? Or a _percentage_ discount amount?

Comment: Hi Matteo, It would be great if you create [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I can't even see the code where `discountAmount` is being _applied_.

Comment: @mjwills dollar discount amount

Comment: So why do you expect 1200 - 20 == 960? 1200 - 20 == 1180, and that is what you are getting now.

Comment: `salesOrder.totalOrderAmount = salesOrder.salesOrderLine.Sum(x => x.totalAmount) * 0.8;` ?

Comment: @mjwills because I don't want to in this way. I'm trying to change the code, but I can't understand what I'm missing

Comment: @HansKilian I have an error: `Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'decimal' and 'double'`

Comment: @Matteo You need to make 0.8 a decimal constant by writing `0.8m`. Sorry about that-